# Can't get proper scrollview direction because of bounce

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I am trying to hide an element synced to the scroll. But the scroll bounce effect mess up my animation.

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
            "Animate UIView up"
        }
        else if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y){
            "Animate UIView down"
    }
```

Is there any other way I can get the direction I am scorlling without the bounce messing it up. I dont want to disable the bounce either.

Also since I am animating my uiview synced to the scroll, eg I scroll 10px up then the uiview height should be minimized by 10px do I then need layoutifneeded() or any other function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it's bouncing you can assume that it's scrolling "out of bounds", you can check for that like this and only animate the view when it's not out of bounds.

```
//Bouncing at the bottom
scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.bounds.size.height > scrollView.contentSize.height;
// Bouncing at the top
scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0
```

You might need to tweak this code if you the `contentInset` property is different from `UIEdgeInsetZero`